# JQUERY: Keep Class in last appended element and remove from all other newly added elements in a TABLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table & in each TR if I click the icon a new TR is appended to the end.
TR also has a row_seperator class. I want this row_seperator to be removed from previous all newly appended rows but remain in the last appended row TR.

```
$(this).closest('tr').removeClass("row_seperator") ;      
$('.new_row').removeClass('row_seperator').removeClass('new_row');
$('<tr class="row_seperator new_row"><td colspan="8">new td</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
```

As shown below in the image. I want these two crossed lines to disappear & the last line to remain. So that each section has a line to separate it from other sections.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `this` refers to the icon clicked. In which case `$(this).closest('tr')` will be always the TR with "Section-A" (or -B, -C, depending on which icon was clicked). And this means that each new TR will be inserted **above** the previous TRs, so it will be always the **first** new TR that must have the `row_separator` class.

If all what I supposed is correct, I would simply check if `$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('row_separator')`, and if so, I would call `removeClass` on it and `addClass` on the new element (or include the class in the string as you did). If not, I would do neither.

If - on the other hand - you would like to insert new TRs **after the previous new TRs**, you can add some distinctive class to the TRs having the icon and call `$(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('distinctive_class').last().after(newTr);`

Also be aware that if you have added some new TRs after Section-A, B and C and call `$('.new_row').removeClass('new_row');` it will remove class from every `.new_row` not only from the ones after the TR of the icon clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table class="authors-list">
       <tr class="row_seperator">
          <td>Column 1</td>
          <td>Column 2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="row_seperator">
          <td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add</a>


// Jquery Code


        var counter = 1;
        $('a.add-author').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            counter++;
            $(".authors-list tr").addClass("row_seperator");
            var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
                counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
                counter + '"/></td></tr>');
            $('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
        });
```

Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/1097/

Comment: No this solution wont work. I need to keep row_seperator for each TR except the newly added TRs. Because each section as you can see in the image has a line separator. I am adding new TR between existing 2 TRs.

Comment: Your question above says something different which is not relevant to your comment..Anyways that also can be achieved with a slight modification..Wait till i update the code